# How to search or filter results when limited amount of data per api request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, redux

I am using an api which gives me max. 100 items per request. Now I have implemented a search and filter - however of course only the fetched items are being searched/filtered (making my search /filter logic almost pointless).

My only idea so far was to keep calling the function that makes the api request until I get all of the data and only then show the search/filter field. However, fetching all of the data will last about a minute.

Is there a better way to do that ?

Ps. I am using redux / react.

Comment: I would suggest, when you fetch next patch of items, maintain a variable for filteredUptoIndex. change your filter logic to take start index also as parameter. append the next filtered results to already filtered results.

Reset your variable, and filteredResults array if filters are changed or reset.

Comment: Are you sure you can't implement the filter in the API?

Comment: The api provides only 3 filter options which are not the ones I want or at least not all of them..

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution for this would be the backend to create a new search API.

The other options will be inefficient and could be buggy. But something you could try are to fetch all items periodically and store it locally and search from that.

Comment: So what I am doing now is fetching all items in an iteration, then use Promise.all to resolve all of them. Why do you think it could lead to bugs and inefficiency? Thanks!

Comment: Fetching all items leads to many requests to backend and will be slow. What if something was changed in the backend during that time?